# Autocomplete with input field added dynamically

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm using a form code copied from [here](http://www.phpcodify.com/add-remove-input-fields-dynamically-using-jquery-bootstrap/) that allows the user to add input fields.

```
<form action="" >
    <div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">
   <input type="text" name="q[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here" id="autocomplete-key">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</button>
      </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:#55BC8A;border:none">Pesquisa</button>
</form>

<!-- Copy Fields-These are the fields which we get through jquery and then add after the above input,-->
<div class="copy-fields hide">
  <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
    <input type="text" name="q[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here" id="autocomplete-key">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I want to add autocomplete from a fixed set of possibilities. For that I'm using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var location_input=$('input[id="autocomplete-key"]');
        location_input.autocomplete({
          source: "/api/get_key_name/",
          minLength: 2
        });
      } );

    //   keeps same width as box
      jQuery.ui.autocomplete.prototype._resizeMenu = function () {
          var ul = this.menu.element;
          ul.outerWidth(this.element.outerWidth());
        }
</script>
```

It works fine for the first input field, but it doesn't work with the added new input fields.

UPDATE: I made a snippet to better exemplify the problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

//here first get the contents of the div with name class copy-fields and add it to after "after-add-more" div class.
  $(".add-more").click(function(){
      var html = $(".copy-fields").html();
      $(".after-add-more").after(html);
  });
//here it will remove the current value of the remove button which has been pressed
  $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){
      $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
  });

});
 
 var availableTutorials  =  [
               "ActionScript",
               "Bootstrap",
               "C",
               "C++",
            ];
 
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($('.autocomplete'), function(i,e) {
        $(e).autocomplete({
            source: availableTutorials,
            minLength: 2,

        });
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <form action="" >
     <div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">
       <input type="text" name="q[]" class="autocomplete form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
       <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</button>
       </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:#55BC8A;border:none">Pesquisa</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Copy Fields-These are the fields which we get through jquery and then add after the above input,-->
    <div class="copy-fields hide">
      <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
        <input type="text" name="q[]" class="autocomplete form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're using `id` which is unique , use class and add the `autocomplete` to all the inputs :

html :

```
<input type="text" name="q[]" class="autocomplete form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here" id="autocomplete-key">
```

js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($('.autocomplete'), function(i,e) {
        $(e).autocomplete({
            source: "/api/get_key_name/",
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working. The newly added input keeps not showing the autocomplete suggestions.